# App crash on resp.getMessage() call

Tags: android, web-services, response

i want to get server response during register process, but unfortunately my app keeps crashing here

```
 response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

            ServerResponse resp = response.body();
//crash occurs here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resp.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and this is what logcat says

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.chat.ServerResponse.getMessage()' on a null object reference
                                                              at com.chat.RegisterActivity$3.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:130)
                                                              at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
```

below is my serverResponse class

```
public class ServerResponse {

private String result;
private String message;
private User user;

public String getResult() {
    return result;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: your `rep.getMessage()` is `null` so your app is crashing.

Comment: post your ServerResponse Pojo class

Comment: @stephingeorge I just edited and added it

Comment: please see my below answer

Comment: @stephingeorge i will try the code when i'm close to my pc.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** your **method** like this:

```
response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

            ServerResponse resp = response.body();

            //check your resp is null or resp.getMessage() is nul here
            if(resp!=null && resp.getMessage() != null)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resp.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

it'll solve your problem.

Comment: If I do that then no response is gotten at all and nothing happens

Comment: it because your response is `null` check your response or share your response here

Comment: I just added my `serverResponse.class`

Comment: *Debug* and see what is `response` in your `onResponse` method.

Comment: I think your response is null so fix it from server side.

Comment: would you like to see the php files?

Comment: Just share what you get in your `response`

Comment: in my php files?

Comment: yeah, what you're receiving n your `onResponse` method?

Comment: I tested it with postman and it worked fine. I think the problem is coming from `resp.getMessage()` logcat points to it

Answer (score 0):

The crash might be due to the implementation of Toast, create a separate function for toast then declare it, and it seems that toast is falling in the loop. It results in the crash of app.

Comment: how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have created the pojo class like this format..

```
 public class ServerResponse {

@SerializedName("MESSAGE")
private String MESSAGE;

@SerializedName("MESSAGE")
public void setMESSAGE(String MESSAGE) {
    this.MESSAGE= MESSAGE;
}
@SerializedName("MESSAGE")
public String getMessage() {
    return MESSAGE;
}
}
```

Comment: please print the response in this format .                    Log.w("reseP", new Gson().toJson(response));